# ¿Cómo ordenar reporte trimestral en power bi?

Tags: powerbi, data, microsoft-office

Buen día
Estoy intentando hacer un reporte trimestral para hacer un histórico en power bi, pero al momento de hacer la grafica no me ordena los trimestres

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe como ordenar esa información?